# sign-ups only to people who live in a certain town

Tags: wordpress, authentication, location, ip

I am building a community based site which I only want people who live in the town to be able to sign up to. Is it possible in some way to achieve this programmatically?

At the moment the only idea I have is to have a series of questions which only residents would know. If they answer them all correctly then they can sign up. This is a programming question and answer site so hopefully somebody here can assist with a way of doing this without the cumbersome questionnaire (which is full of flaws itself)

I have only seen ways to limit people from certain countries. Maybe something to do with their IP addresses. Also I most probably will be using wordPress but I can look into alternatives.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult problem without an existing solution. It's difficult to identify who lives in a location. There are solutions depending on where you live (like accessing the town assessment records online), or other public information you may be able to access from your town clerks vital statistics records.

Here are some potential solutions that could fit your needs.

1. **Geolocation** - you can use a google or another geolocation product to find the persons current location. If they are in an address within the towns borders then let them enter the site. This of course won't validate that the person lives the town but will provide you the location of the device they are logging in from. [google geocoded](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)
2. **Facebook login API** - you could hook your website into the Facebook login API and query the user's indicated location. You will need to request permission to this node. This approach won't fake addresses (my Facebook says I live in Austria for example). [facebook login - location node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/)

Comment: Great both options look viable although many of the residents are older and may not have a Facebook account. Saying that my nan is 84 and she has one so it could still be the way to go. Thanks for your suggestions Dom.